# C++11 regex capture file name with optional extension

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm using `g++ 4.9.0`, so it does support regular expressions :) I'm trying to extract file name with an optional extension:

```
#include <regex>

smatch match_result;
regex pattern("/home/user/(.+)(\\.png)?$");
if (!regex_search("/home/user/image.png", match_result, pattern) {
    throw runtime_error("Path does not match the pattern.");
}

cout << "File name: " << match_result[1] << '\n';
```

Running this snippet, outputs me `image.png` while I was expecting `image`. Apparently the `+` quantifier is greedy and ignores the following pattern `(\\.png)?$`.
Is there anyway to avoid this? Or should I trim the extension manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(.+?)`. The question mark makes the pattern not greedy. I guess you will also need `^`.

The complete pattern: `"^/home/user/(.+?)(\\.png)?$"`.

You may also want to use ignore-case matching.

Answer (score 0):

Get the matched group from index 1.

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wK7iZ4/3)

String literals for use in programs:

C#

```
@"\/(\w+)\.png$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example does not use `regex pattern("/home/user/(.+)(\\.png)?$")`. It uses a new regex you create when you call regex_search():

```
regex_search("/home/user/image.png", match_result, regex("/home/user/(.+)"))
```

The regex you actually use does not check for the `.png` extension.

Try this:

```
regex_search("/home/user/image.png", match_result, pattern)
```

Comment: Oh, my bad. Actualy I was trying with ``regex_search("/home/user/image.png", match_result, pattern)``. It did not work.